# Need help finishing my first attempt at a state machine for a test timer app - I think I still have transition errors

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So this is a countdown timer app with a pickerview where you select the time, a delegate that takes that time and gets its seconds value and starts the countdown timer. I'm trying to write the timer portion as a state machine but I'm still having 2 issues with the transitions:

- I can hit play and the timer starts to run but then when I hit pause, it doesn't pause. The play and pause are both UIButtons that sit at the same x,y in IB and I am hiding one and showing the other and vice versa - is this my problem?
- Any improvements to my state machine? I feel like I overcomplicated things.

Answer (score 0):

> The play and pause are both UIButtons that sit at the same x,y in IB and I am hiding one and showing the other and vice versa - is this my problem?

Nope, there's nothing inherently wrong with this approach. I find your state machine code hard to follow, so I'm not sure what's going wrong there - but have you tried debugging what happens when you press the Pause button? Does the state end up as what you expect it to be?

> When the view first loads and you immediately hit play without moving the pickerview, it doesn't get the first pickerView selection of 3 mins and instead starts a countdown at 0.

This happens because the `didSelectRow` method of the `PickerView` hasn't run at all at this point, so the timer starts with your initial value for `counter`, which is 0.

> Any improvements to my state machine?

A couple of things stand out to me:

- You have an `isTimerRunning` var on your VC, but shouldn't you be relying on your state machine for this value?
- `getStateOfStateMachine` doesn't actually "get" anything, so it should probably be renamed.
- The names for your `TimerState` values and `TimerTransition` values are too similar - it makes the code quite hard to read. Maybe you consider renaming them to `NotRunningState`, `StartedTransition`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for comment. The Pause button is being called, just not doing any pausing. It should pause and switch back to the Play button for a potential restart. I can play and cancel just fine. I also refactored the names so hopefully its better now. I also added counter = 180 to my viewdidload so it should start at my first struct value of 3 mins if user does not spin pickerview and get DidSelectRow - is this the best way to do this?